# Main WP page and subfolder WP with the same name. How to prioritize for main Wp

Tags: directory

I have second WP site in subfolder. I need to give priority to main site if they conflict.

In main site I have pages like:

- site.com/author/john
- site.com/author/robert

And I installed second WP in "author" folder:

site.com/author (This is second WP site)

And now, the page **site.com/author/john** does not work.

When entered

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /author/?$
```

in .htaccess the page site.com/author/john works but then **site.com/author/hello-world** does not work.

What I need is both **site.com/author/john** and **site.com/author/hello-world** (post in second site) work.

How to achieve that?

Comment: What is the purpose of this site in the subfolder? I have to imagine there's a better solution. Either a subdomain or something on the main site.

Comment: If I can not found solution, I will create a subdomain. I have created user area for authors in the second Wp. So they can send content without login to main Wp.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Seems like it would be better to just give them the appropriate roles & capabilities so they can only do what you need them to.

Comment: Yeh, I could help you with this, but I'm all against supporting bad practices :) Just create proper user roles